# Вопрос по использованию сервлетов

Tags: java, servlet

Такой вопрос, как лучше использовать сервлеты? Для каждого типа запросов свой сервлет или один большой сервлет, который принимает все запросы и в зависимости от этих запросов выполняет то или иное действие? Что из вышеописанного является лучшей практикой при программировании на Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имхо. Вообще сервлет лучше делить не по типам запросов, а по логике, которую он делает. Например, в сервлет, отвечающий за возврат картинок следует помещать любые запросы, связанные с картинками. Если он становится большой по размеру и сложно охватываемый взглядом, можно разбить его на меньшие сервлеты, но поделить логически обоснованно. 
P.S. Сервлеты хороши, когда тебе нужно сделать что-то очень маленькое. Обычно используют что-нибудь вроде RestController и Controller спринга.